# How to find items in a collection whose IDs are in an array?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, sails.js

I have a collection named `Vendor` and I want to find all vendors whose IDs are in a list of IDs. Is there any way to do it in Sails.js or I must iterate over the list to find those whose IDs match with one item in the list.

I'm using MongoDB in Sails.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the **[`$in`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/in/)** operator within the **[`.native()`](http://sailsjs.org/documentation/reference/waterline-orm/models/native)** method as follows

```
Vendor.native(function(err, collection) {
    if (err) return console.log(err);
    collection.find({ "_id": { "$in": ids } }).toArray(function(err, results) {
        console.log(results);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

As you can see in [doc](https://github.com/balderdashy/waterline-docs/blob/master/queries/query-language.md#in-pairs):

```
Vendor.find({
  id: ids // ids is Array 
})
.then(vendors => {...})
.catch(err => {...});
```